# usage of spring integration in bound channel adapter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am new to spring. I have a query.

can a channel or router activate `<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>` ?

i mean, a router should be able to initiate polling. is it possible?

Comment: and what are you trying to achieve from this?

Comment: i have spring applicationContext file which has logic to poll the file system and get the xml and process it and place in another folder. now i need to get the processed xml from another folder and do some processsing...

Answer (score 0):

`int-file:inbound-channel-adapter`  will need a  `int:poller`  to read from file system. You can decide what is your polling interval. Once the file has been read by the  `int-file:inbound-channel-adapter`  you can pass it on to a channel. So overall your code will look like:

```
 <file:inbound-channel-adapter id="fileInAdapter" channel="sendFileToThisChannel"
      directory="C:\FilesToBeRead" auto-create-directory="true" auto-startup="true">
    <int:poller id="packagePoller" fixed-rate="${file-adapter.polling.interval:5000}"/>
 </file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Here the inboud-channel-adapter will check for files from FilesToBeRead in C:, every 5 seconds and if it finds the file, it will send a message to sendFileToThisChannel. From the channel onwards, you can do what you do want to do with message - route it, process it, activate a service or anything you want!

If you want to make sure a file which is passed once should not be passed again, you can take a look at AcceptOnceFileListFilter